# How to load .css file after downloading it in local storage using InAppWebview flutter

Tags: html, css, flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview

I would like to load the contents of a CSS file which will contain the fonts like KaTeX_AMS-Regular.woff2.

So, the CSS file contains the content like file `main.css`

```
@font-face{font-family:abcd_AMS;src:url(fonts/abcd_AMS-Regular.woff2) format("woff2"),url(fonts/abcd_AMS-Regular.woff) format("woff"),url(fonts/abcd_AMS-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");font-weight:400;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:abcd_Caligraphic;src:url(fonts/abcd_Caligraphic-Bold.woff2) format("woff2"),url(fonts/abcd_Caligraphic-Bold.woff) format("woff")
```

so these font file I am downloading at a file path and loading the html like this

destinationFilePath.path will be the path where the contents of css are downloaded.
File content will be like:

root --> content --> main.css

root --> content --> fonts --> abcd_Caligraphic-Bold.woff
root --> content --> fonts --> abcd_Caligraphic-Bold.woff2
... and so on

```
String htmlContent = """<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
       <head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="${Uri.file(destinationFilePath.path)}"> <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover, initial-scale=1'/>
      <body style='margin:0;padding:0;};'>
          $data
      </body>
      </html>
      """;
```

The above code works properly in android but it does not read the css font file contents in iOS.

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview package to load the contents in webview.

```js
InAppWebView(
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
        disableVerticalScroll : true,
        disableHorizontalScroll : true,
        disableContextMenu: true,
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        allowFileAccessFromFileURLs: true,
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs: true),
    ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      allowingReadAccessTo: Uri.file(fontFilePath.path),
    ),
  ),
  initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(data: htmlContent),
  
);
```

Using the above code snippet, it will work perfectly fine in Android but not on iOS